# Linux memory usage: Can we consider memory full when swap is unused?

Tags: linux, performance, memory

I am checking available free memory after deploying our applications. I am using below command and finding free memory is less than 20%:

```
free | grep Mem | awk '{print "Free Memory :"100*($4+$6+$7)/$2"%"}'
```

But when i check top command, i see that swap memory is not used at all. also above command doesn't include swap memory space. Now i have several questions in my mind

**Snapshot1:**

```
 top - 10:01:07 up 305 days, 11:23,  1 user,  load average: 0.35, 0.22, 0.12
Tasks: 244 total,   1 running, 242 sleeping,   0 stopped,   1 zombie
Cpu(s): 13.4%us, 14.5%sy,  0.0%ni, 69.3%id,  0.8%wa,  0.4%hi,  1.6%si,  0.0%st
Mem:     15952M total,    15817M used,      135M free,      531M buffers
Swap:    16378M total,        0M used,    16378M free,     2567M cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND           
19983 user1       20   0 3410m 2.9g 4420 S   23 18.9  56733:33 x1             
28390 user2      20   0  621m 216m 1300 S   12  1.4  40201:39 p2               
24781 user1       20   0 1393m 868m 1760 S    9  5.4  27795:12 p3          
13936 user1       20   0  740m 432m 2692 S    6  2.7  15726:39 p4          
30545 user1       20   0  391m  77m 2232 S    6  0.5   2805:05 p5        
 5696 user1       20   0  914m 680m 2180 S    4  4.3   2209:03 p6                
28801 user2      20   0  282m 148m 1432 S    4  0.9  12408:20 p7                
29559 user2      20   0  504m 357m 2028 S    3  2.2   9152:52 p8                
29129 user2      20   0  245m 172m 2004 S    2  1.1   6935:50 p9                
29130 user2      20   0  245m 172m 1996 S    2  1.1   6879:25 p9                
29131 user2      20   0  245m 172m 1996 S    2  1.1   6913:15 p9                
29135 user2      20   0  245m 172m 1996 S    2  1.1   6897:49 p9                
29140 user2      20   0  245m 172m 1996 S    2  1.1   6886:52 p9
```

**Snapshot 2:**

```
top - 10:06:18 up 312 days, 11:29,  1 user,  load average: 0.26, 0.42, 0.31
Tasks: 240 total,   1 running, 238 sleeping,   0 stopped,   1 zombie
Cpu(s): 13.1%us, 11.8%sy,  0.0%ni, 71.8%id,  1.7%wa,  0.5%hi,  1.1%si,  0.0%st
Mem:     15952M total,    15832M used,      119M free,      480M buffers
Swap:    16378M total,        0M used,    16378M free,     2622M cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND           
19983 user1       20   0 3410m 2.9g 5292 S   18 18.9  58711:30 x1             
28390 user2      20   0  621m 216m 1300 S   12  1.4  41451:12 p2               
24781 user1       20   0 1393m 868m 1760 S    8  5.4  28615:15 p3          
13936 user1       20   0  740m 432m 2692 S    6  2.7  16247:35 p4          
12453 user1       20   0  387m  74m 3056 S    5  0.5 178:45.72 p5        
28801 user2      20   0  282m 148m 1448 S    4  0.9  12794:23 p6                
13252 user1       20   0  850m 665m 2556 S    4  4.2 138:43.83 p7                
29559 user2      20   0  504m 357m 1992 S    3  2.2   9450:05 p8                
29154 user2      20   0  245m 172m 1972 S    3  1.1   7127:40 p9                
29130 user2      20   0  245m 172m 1972 S    2  1.1   7104:03 p9                
29140 user2      20   0  245m 172m 1972 S    2  1.1   7111:48 p9                
29171 user2      20   0  244m 172m 1972 S    2  1.1   7137:48 p9                
29129 user2      20   0  245m 172m 1980 S    2  1.1   7162:12 p9
```

Am i using correct method to check available free space? (I need to raise alarm when memory usage is too high)

2.From below 2 snapshots i see that free memory is reduced from "135M free" to "119M free" (Pls check mem: row of top command). But i see that memory related to my processes (even other) not changed but only that buffers and cache reduced. As i have read earlier these memory will be released by OS if enough memory is not available for processes. So should i really worry about this change? is there any way to clear this?

3. My system has Mem:15952M total, Swap:16378M total so what is the total available space? will the system performance will go down once swap memory starts being used?

Pls guide me

**Example free memory output:**

```
>free 
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       8183648    7148324    1035324          0     150568    2352956
-/+ buffers/cache:    4644800    3538848
Swap:     17149376      24588   17124788
```

Comment: You need not worry about buffers and cache they are used for disk caching are are always available for applications to consume. Read up : http://www.linuxatemyram.com/

Comment: Total available memory is Virtual memory=RAM+SWAP. Of course paging/swapping is significantly slower compared physical memory access.

Comment: Instead of relying on all these internal details shouldnt there be any api to get this info? Like get availablemem() or freemem() some thing like this?